# Problema ao fazer a inserção de dados no SQLite e atualizar a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, android-studio, sqlite

Estou tento problemas no meu banco SQLite, onde eu criei um método no meu `DatabaseController.java` que se chama `recuperarUltimoDigitado()` - esse método recupera o valor inserido e logo atualiza a lista.

No entanto, isso gera um erro na primeira tentativa de inserir os dados, mas ao abrir novamente o app e adicionar um novo dado, apresenta uma repetição na listagem do mesmo dado anteriormente inserido na `RecyclerView` e, após isso, os próximos dados são inseridos e listados normalmente, mas eu gostaria de saber o que eu poderia fazer para que isso seja resolvido e funcione corretamente.

```
public class DatabaseController {

    private DatabaseInit databaseInit;
    private SQLiteDatabase sql;

    public DatabaseController(Context context) {
        databaseInit = new DatabaseInit(context);
        sql = databaseInit.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public long inserir(Livro livro){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Const.AUTOR_LIVRO, livro.getAutor());
        values.put(Const.EDITORA_LIVRO, livro.getEditora());
        values.put(Const.TITULO_LIVRO, livro.getTitulo());

        return sql.insert(Const.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    }

    public ArrayList<Livro> recuperar(){
        ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT " +
                Const.TITULO_LIVRO  +  "," +
                Const.EDITORA_LIVRO  +  "," +
                Const.AUTOR_LIVRO  + " FROM "+
                Const.TABLE_NAME , null);

        int indexColumnTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.TITULO_LIVRO);
        int indexColumnAuthor = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.AUTOR_LIVRO);
        int indexColumnEditor = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.EDITORA_LIVRO);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            Livro livro = new Livro();
            livro.setTitulo(cursor.getString(indexColumnTitle));
            livro.setEditora(cursor.getString(indexColumnEditor));
            livro.setAutor(cursor.getString(indexColumnAuthor));
            livros.add(livro);
        }

        cursor.close();

        return livros;
    }

    public Livro recuperarUltimoDigitado(){

        Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Const.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY ID DESC", null);

        int indexColumnTitle = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.TITULO_LIVRO);
        int indexColumnAuthor = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.AUTOR_LIVRO);
        int indexColumnEditor = cursor.getColumnIndex(Const.EDITORA_LIVRO);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
            String titulo = cursor.getString(indexColumnTitle);
            String autor = cursor.getString(indexColumnAuthor);
            String editora = cursor.getString(indexColumnEditor);
            cursor.close();
            return new Livro(id, titulo, autor, editora);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Método no adaptador para notificar a atualização da lista:

```
    public void adicionarLiivro(Livro livro){
        livros.add(livro);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
    }
```

Activity Principal:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText autor, titulo, editora;
    private DatabaseController controller;
    private Button btn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Livro> livros;
    private ArrayList<Livro> livrosFiltrados = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      autor = findViewById(R.id.autorId);
      titulo = findViewById(R.id.tituloId);
      editora = findViewById(R.id.editoraId);
      controller = new DatabaseController(this);
      livros = controller.recuperar();
      livrosFiltrados.addAll(livros);
      recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rcyId);

      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

      final AdapterListBooks adapter = new AdapterListBooks(livrosFiltrados);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

      btn = findViewById(R.id.btnId);

      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Livro livro = new Livro();

              Livro livroRertono = controller.recuperarUltimoDigitado();
              adapter.adicionarLiivro(livroRertono);


              livro.setAutor(autor.getText().toString());
              livro.setTitulo(titulo.getText().toString());
              livro.setEditora(editora.getText().toString());

              long id = controller.inserir(livro);

              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Livro inserido com o Id: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
      });

    }
}
```

Acredito que o foco do problema seja no método `recuperarUltimoDigitado()`.

Answer (score 0):

Por que depois de inserir voce nao usa o metodo recuperar() pra atualizar e trazer tudo? Depois adiciona no seu List e joga no adapter...

```
  public void adicionarLiivro(Livro livro){
        livros.add(livro);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
        recuperar();
    }
```

Comment: Sua resposta não deu muito certo e agora não consigo nem inserir dados no banco...

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei um pouco mais e fiz algumas edições no código, onde procurei realizar uma verificação se houve ou não o salvamento de dados (Usando valor booleano). Desta maneira no evento de click do botão, fiz a inserção normalmente, mas utilizando uma variável `sucesso` recebendo a o método `inserir()` que retorna `true` ou `false`, isto é, se foi ou não inseridos os dados... Deixarei a solução aqui, para caso alguém em frente um problema parecido...

Alteração feita na classe `DatabaseController.java`.

```
public boolean inserir(Livro livro){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(Const.AUTOR_LIVRO, livro.getAutor());
        values.put(Const.EDITORA_LIVRO, livro.getEditora());
        values.put(Const.TITULO_LIVRO, livro.getTitulo());

        return sql.insert(Const.TABLE_NAME, null, values) > 0;

    }
```

Alteração feita na classe `MainActivity.java` e no `btn`.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Livro livro = new Livro();

              livro.setAutor(autor.getText().toString());
              livro.setTitulo(titulo.getText().toString());
              livro.setEditora(editora.getText().toString());

              controller = new DatabaseController(getBaseContext());
              boolean sucesso = controller.inserir(livro);

              if (sucesso) {

                  Livro livroRertono = controller.recuperarUltimoDigitado();
                  adapter.adicionarLiivro(livroRertono);


                  Snackbar.make(v, "Salvou!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                          .setAction("Action", null).show();

              }else{
                  Snackbar.make(v, "Consulte o LOG!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                          .setAction("Action", null).show();
              }

          }
      });
```